# org-mode: headline levels when exporting to ascii

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

With thisoptions in my .org file:

```
#+OPTIONS    H:5
```

... headlines below level 3 are still exported as list items when exportning to ascii.

How do I change that?

In addition: how can I get all headlines to be exported as the plain text of the org node minus the stars. That is exporting this:

```
* Headline 1
** Headline 2
```

To this:

```
Headline 1
Headline 2
```

Instead of this:

```
Headline 1
==========
Headline 2 
----------
```

**Edit:**

With regard to the headline levels I also tried to add this to .emacs:

```
(setq org-export-headline-levels 5)
```

That gives me this error when exporting to ascii:

```
Wrong type argument: characterp, 67108896
```

I get that headline levels rely on the document class when exporting to latex but why can't I change the headline level to anything I'd like when exporting to ascii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the newest stable version of org-mode (8.2.5h) made this easy-peachy. Now:

```
#+OPTIONS    H:5
```

... actually works.

This works to get rid of the underlinings:

```
(setq org-ascii-underline (quote ((ascii) (latin1) (utf-8))))
```

In addition this contributes to get the clean look I was going for:

```
(setq org-ascii-headline-spacing (quote (1 . 1)))

(setq org-ascii-inner-margin 0)
```